# Can't return an XML formatted string, using stringbuilder in C# and a DB Template, For a PlaceHolder

Tags: c#, xml, stringbuilder

Good Afternoon,

I have a function that builds a string for a template in my DB that outputs an XML structure. It takes in a Order class as a parameter and a Template, well I am having troubles trying to populate a placeholder tag named [[items]], where based on the number of items in the table it should build the xml list for that portion.

This is the Template, It is only returning one instance of the string but it should return (n) instances based on what's in the table.

```
<Items>
   [[items]]
</Items>
```

This is what should be populated for the other tags for the item

```
<Item>
 <SKU>[[item_sku]]</SKU>
 <PROD_NAME><![CDATA[[[item_product_name]]]]></PROD_NAME>
 <Description><![CDATA[[[item_name]]]]></Description>
 <Attributes><![CDATA[[[item_attributes]]]]></Attributes>
 <Quantity>[[item_qty]]</Quantity>
 <UnitPrice>[[item_price]]</UnitPrice>
 <InkColor>[[item_inkcolor]]</InkColor>
</Item>
```

And It want to populate like this

```
<Items>
  <Item>
    <SKU>7Z-BRPA-K79A</SKU>
    <PROD_NAME><![CDATA[Test One]]></PROD_NAME>
    <Description><![CDATA[ExcelMark 5-Line Large Return Address Stamp - Custom Self Inking Rubber Stamp]]></Description>
    <Attributes><![CDATA[Custom Text Line 1 Text: This book was donated to CAEO Font: Arial
                Custom Text Line 2 Text: In tribute to & memory of Font: Arial]]></Attributes>
    <Quantity>1</Quantity>
    <UnitPrice><![CDATA[$9.99]]></UnitPrice>
    <InkColor>Red</InkColor>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <SKU>42A1848</SKU>
    <PROD_NAME><![CDATA[Test Two]]></PROD_NAME>
    <Description><![CDATA[Self Inking Rubber Stamp with up To 4 Lines of Custom Text]]></Description>
    <Attributes><![CDATA[Custom Text Line 1 Text: This book was donated to CAEO Font: Arial
                Custom Text Line 2 Text: In tribute to & memory of Font: Arial]]></Attributes>
    <Quantity>1</Quantity>
    <UnitPrice><![CDATA[$8.99]]></UnitPrice>
    <InkColor>Blue</InkColor>
  </Item>
</Items>
```

Here is the function to make it happen

```
public string PopulateStringBuilder(Order order, Template template)
    {
        var i = new StringBuilder(template.Description);
        List<string> s = new List<string>();
        var reqID = order.OrderId;

            foreach (var x in order.Items)
            {
                i.Replace("[[item_sku]]", x.SkuNumber);
                i.Replace("[[item_product_name]]", x.ProductName);
                i.Replace("[[item_name]]", x.Description);
                i.Replace("[[item_attributes]]", x.Attributes);
                i.Replace("[[item_qty]]", x.Quantity.ToString());
                i.Replace("[[item_price]]", x.UnitPrice.ToString());
                i.Replace("[[item_inkcolor]]", x.InkColor);
                o.Replace("[[items]]", i.ToString());
            }  
        return o.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing it the correct way

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Item> items = new List<Item>() {
                new Item() {
                    SKU = "7Z-BRPA-K79A",
                    PROD_NAME = "Test One",
                    Description = "ExcelMark 5-Line Large Return Address Stamp - Custom Self Inking Rubber Stamp",
                    Attributes = "Custom Text Line 1 Text: This book was donated to CAEO Font: Arial" +
                            " Custom Text Line 2 Text: In tribute to & memory of Font: Arial",
                    Quantity = 1,
                    UnitPrice =  "$9.99",
                    InkColor = "Red"
                },
                new Item() {
                    SKU = "42A1848",
                    PROD_NAME = "Test Two",
                    Description = "Self Inking Rubber Stamp with up To 4 Lines of Custom Text",
                    Attributes = "Custom Text Line 1 Text: This book was donated to CAEO Font: Arial" +
                           " Custom Text Line 2 Text: In tribute to & memory of Font: Arial",
                    Quantity = 1,
                    UnitPrice = "$8.99",
                    InkColor = "Blue"
                }
            };
            XElement xItems = new XElement("Items");

            foreach (Item item in items)
            {
                XElement xItem = new XElement("Item", new object[] {
                    new XElement("SKU", item.SKU),
                    new XElement("PROD_NAME",  new XCData(item.PROD_NAME)),
                    new XElement("Description", new XCData(item.Description)),
                    new XElement("Attribute", new XCData(item.Attributes)),
                    new XElement("Quantity", item.Quantity),
                    new XElement("UnitPrice", new XCData(item.UnitPrice)),
                    new XElement("InkColor", item.InkColor)
                });
                xItems.Add(xItem);
            }
        }
    }
    public class Item
    {
        public string SKU { get; set; }
        public string PROD_NAME { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Attributes { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        public string UnitPrice { get; set; }
        public string InkColor { get; set; }
    }
}


//<Items>
//  <Item>
//    <SKU>7Z-BRPA-K79A</SKU>
//    <PROD_NAME><![CDATA[Test One]]></PROD_NAME>
//    <Description><![CDATA[ExcelMark 5-Line Large Return Address Stamp - Custom Self Inking Rubber Stamp]]></Description>
//    <Attributes><![CDATA[Custom Text Line 1 Text: This book was donated to CAEO Font: Arial
//                Custom Text Line 2 Text: In tribute to & memory of Font: Arial]]></Attributes>
//    <Quantity>1</Quantity>
//    <UnitPrice><![CDATA[$9.99]]></UnitPrice>
//    <InkColor>Red</InkColor>
//  </Item>
//  <Item>
//    <SKU>42A1848</SKU>
//    <PROD_NAME><![CDATA[Test Two]]></PROD_NAME>
//    <Description><![CDATA[Self Inking Rubber Stamp with up To 4 Lines of Custom Text]]></Description>
//    <Attributes><![CDATA[Custom Text Line 1 Text: This book was donated to CAEO Font: Arial
//                Custom Text Line 2 Text: In tribute to & memory of Font: Arial]]></Attributes>
//    <Quantity>1</Quantity>
//    <UnitPrice><![CDATA[$8.99]]></UnitPrice>
//    <InkColor>Blue</InkColor>
//  </Item>
//</Items>
```